# How should I make a Plone content type with a downloadable File field?

Tags: plone, archetypes

I am trying to make a Plone content type with Archetypes that holds exactly two downloadable files as `plone.app.blob.FileField`. How do I make it so those fields can be traversed to and then downloaded?

Answer (score 3):

The spelling for the download URL is just `content-item/at_download/field-name`. The content type doesn't have to do anything special to support downloadable `Blob` fields.

Comment: You mean at_download, not aq_download.